# How far is "Nearby" for the purposes of "The Falcon Takes Flight"?

Tags: l5r-4e, special-abilities

The Toritaka Bushi School gets the following Rank 2 trait:

> The Falcon Takes Flight - Through his training, the Toritaka can sense the emanations of **nearby** spirits as they cross over into the mortal realm. You may attempt to detect the presence of any creatures from other Spirit Realms by making a Perception Trait Roll against a TN equal to the creature's Air Ring x 5.

How far is "Nearby" in this sentence? It's hard to tell for me, if that is the same room, 100 feet or the reach of about one village/castle/town!

The very similar *Sense* spells for Rukugani spellcasters limited to one element have a range of about 50 feet, and the *Sense Void* has one of 25 feet.

Comment: I know 3.5e D&D had Perception penalties for every 10 ft away the target was - does L5R have such a penalty?

Comment: @Phoenices **L5R-4E does not play at all like D&D 3.5** and doesn't hevne have a *perception roll* to notice stuff. Perception is one of the attributes, but you roll it with a skill to determine if you figure something out. Distance is not listed as part of any Investigation (notice)/Perception rolls in the book, the spells mentioned have no such component either - they are boolean: you feel it the moment it is inside.